# LLVM disable the stack

Tags: llvm

When compiling a language which uses heap allocated closures holding by-val or pointers to heap allocated arguments, how might one guarantee that LLVM doesn't generate code which uses the stack (and optionally use ebp/esp as another general-purpose register)?

The function may be running in a strand/microthread which doesn't have a C/traditional stack at all.

---

**Edit**

An article that might be relevant, but it doesn't say whether there is a guarantee LLVM won't try and consume stack.

http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/ExplicitlyManagedStackFrames.txt

---

**Edit 2**

To be clear, I don't need the stack for regular calls because I can generate new closures with pointers to old closures so that the state is proper on returning from a call.

Think of this as just a linked stack.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to code your own backend. The existing x86/x64 backends will not be programmed to support this- stack use is basically mandatory for virtually all functions. You could lower alloca() instructions to your own pseudo-stack which is really on the heap. Not to mention you'd have to develop your own call stack, your own function calling ABIs, all of that nasty stuff. Even then, you're basically down to emulating a stack.

The only programming environments that do not provide a hardware stack and are still even somewhat useful are GPUs, realistically, and that's only because they offer so many available registers and each function is supposed to be very restricted. Only having register space available would cripple programs running on x86 or x64.

Answer (score 2):

The Abstract Machine described by the C++ standard specification clearly describes a stack model. It's used in describing the behaviour of any (non-static) variables with automatic storage. (Member objects might be on the stack if the enclosing object is).

While it's *technically possible* I know of not a single C++ compiler that compiles the code in such a way that the stack is no,t (dynamically) used. (The compile should be emulating the stack in other memory (the heap?) - which would make it much less efficient than using the CPU infrastructure that is *there*. This makes it unlikely that any compiler would ever facilitate this kind of compilation mode.

Now, answering a potential X/Y part of the question, I assume you are looking for a way to implement stackless coroutines: Boost Asio provides *just that*: [Stackless Coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutine.html).

Actually the actor-oriented design of Boost Asio knows about "strands" and you can alternatively use Stackless/Stackful coroutines.

I think you might be most intested in the [HTTP Server Sample using Stackless Coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_4), here's a teaser (server.cpp, comments removed for brevity):

```
reenter(this) {
    do {
        socket_.reset(new tcp::socket(acceptor_->get_io_service()));
        yield acceptor_->async_accept(*socket_, *this);
        fork server(*this)();
    } while(is_parent());

    buffer_.reset(new boost::array<char, 8192>);
    request_.reset(new request);

    do {
        yield socket_->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(*buffer_), *this);
        boost::tie(valid_request_, boost::tuples::ignore)
            = request_parser_.parse(*request_,
                    buffer_->data(), buffer_->data() + length);
    } while(boost::indeterminate(valid_request_));

    reply_.reset(new reply);

    if(valid_request_)
        request_handler_(*request_, *reply_);
    else
        *reply_ = reply::stock_reply(reply::bad_request);

    yield boost::asio::async_write(*socket_, reply_->to_buffers(), *this);
    socket_->shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
}
```

---

<sub>For completeness, there's also Boost Coroutine (which builds on Boost Context) for Stackful Coroutines. These are significantly more heavyweight, as the library will actively save and restore register/stack contents on context switch.</sub>

Comment: Mmm. Just realized I equated llvm with clang++ for a moment there. If that's not appropriate, this answer became unhelpful. I'll remove if that's the case.

Comment: Good answer, worth keeping, but my problem isn't specific to C/C++. I'm more thinking about FPLs being compiled via llvm.

Comment: Without a call stack, you cannot non-tail-recurse. This would destroy any chance of an FPL being any use at all.

Comment: How so? FPLs implement recursion using tail calls.

Comment: Er, only *some* recursion can be converted to a tail call. There's a very large proportion which is not tail callable. In addition, there's serious issues like spilling registers- x86 and x64 have so few that not having a call stack available would be a crippling problem. Not to mention you can kiss goodbye any dynamic indirection, ever, because you can't have a call stack. If you are on x86 and you don't have a hardware stack, you are essentially crippled.

Comment: I think this can be implemented by using linked closures, but I'm not sure. Thanks. I added a link in the first post to an article I found on generating "constant stack space" programs.

Comment: Even ignoring the vast number of unanswered questions about for example, how to implement passing continuations when you can't have a call stack, there's a thousand miles between "constant" and "8 registers only". You can see that even foo and foo2 both consume a number of registers.

Comment: @Puppy As the question clearly states, the stack simply becomes a linked list. Whether it should be kept in a register or not is entirely a question of register pressure and actual usage. There's the mention of a strictly internal thread that does not do OS or C calls, and there you can indeed repurpose the stack register.